# Consistent but not covergent

Tags: numerical-methods

I have been asked to prove that the method:

$$x_{n+3} + x_{n+2} - x_{n+1} - x_n = h\left(f_{n+3} + f_{n+2} + f_{n+1} + f_n\right)$$

is consistent, but not convergent.

I have been able to show that the method is consistent, by showing that $\rho(1) = 0$ and that $\rho'(1) = \sigma(1)$

However, I know from Dahlquist that a method is convergent iff it is consistent and zero stable, which must mean that if this method is consistent but not convergent, there must be a root of $\rho(r)$ that doesn't lie in or on the unit circle.

However, when I take: $$\rho(r) \ = \ r^3 + r^2 - r - 1$$

I see that this is only equal to $0$ when $r=1$

I thought I may have written my method wrong, but having checked the homework sheet I have copied it correctly, so I can't see where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I realised that I can factor my characteristic polynomial to give:$$\rho(r) = r^3 + r^2 - r - 1 = (r-1)(r+1)^2$$

As it has a repeated root of $-1$, and such a magnitude of $1$, it is not zero stable